# How to use 32 bit oracle client for 64 bit Windows by the use of Excel to connect a data base?

Tags: windows, excel, oracle

If I try to connect via Excel to a database I get the following Error:
test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider excel
I searched for the reason  and found that I have to use 32 bit version of Oracle client while  the 64 bit version is at the moment  installed.

I read that I have to add it in `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`
But as one can see in the [image: Picture]
there is no option like `..\oracle11g_32`.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Per microsoft's utterly STUPIDLY MORONIC design ideas, `\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe` is actually the **64BIT** tool. for the 32bit version, you need \windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe.

Comment: I did it but there I can just see the 64 bit client!  How can I put both64 bit and 32 bit in the path?

Comment: check your installs apps. just because a 64bit driver is present doesn't mean a 32bit version would be as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc I solved the problem :) thank you again!